# Two buttons with same class but different Titles, click with javascript

Tags: javascript

According to previous question
[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32436577/click-button-with-javascript)

I have this button 
And i want you to help me to click it with javascript code.
Here is the class of the button.

***Before click***

```
 <a class="UFILikeLink" href="#" role="button" aria-label="Like this" aria-live="polite" data-ft="{"tn":">"}" data-reactid=".19l">

<i class="UFILikeLinkIcon img sp_nbjSKc2Bl8j sx_49c162" data-reactid=".19l.0"></i>

<span data-reactid=".19l.1">Like</span></a>
```

***After click***

```
<a class="UFILikeLink UFILinkBright" href="#" role="button" aria-label="Unlike this" aria-live="polite" data-ft="{"tn":">"}" data-reactid=".19l">

<i class="UFILikeLinkIcon img sp_nbjSKc2Bl8j sx_df3f80" data-reactid=".19l.0">

</i><span data-reactid=".19l.1">Like</span></a>
```

@dikkini made up a solution with this code

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('UFILikeLink'); 
for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++) {
   var ele = el[i];
   if (!hasClass(ele, "UFILinkBright")) {
     ele.click();
   }
}


function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
```

BUT now i have one extra button with the same CLASS but different Title.
And when i execute 2 times the javascript code, the 2nd button is also pushed.
But i dont want it to be pushed at all. No matter how many times i execute the code that dikkini suggested.

The code of this button is this..

```
<a class="UFILikeLink" data-ft="{"tn":">"}" href="#" role="button" title="Like this comment" data-reactid=".1h.1:4:1:$comment535881486576364_535889293242250/=10.0.$right.0.$left.0.3.$likeToggle/=10">Like</a>
```

As you can see it has a Title. Can someone help me make an if statement so if it has this title NOT to push it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: My second solution using 'aria-label' attribute (with JSFiddle link) in previous question solving your problem, doesn't it?

Comment: @dikkini i didnt notice wait.

Answer (score 3):

To check title you can use this:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('UFILikeLink'); 
for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++) {
   var ele = el[i];
   if (!hasClass(ele, "UFILinkBright") && ele.getAttribute('title').indexOf('Like this comment') == -1) {

     ele.click();
   }
}


function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
```

Or your still can check aria-label solution from previous question:

This is for `aria-label` attribute code:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('UFILikeLink'); 
for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++) {
   var ele = el[i];
   if (ele.getAttribute('aria-label').indexOf('Unlike this') == -1) {
     ele.click();
   }
}
```

[`JSFiddel`](http://jsfiddle.net/dikkini/6r3h1z7y/5/) for aria-label attribtue code.

Comment: Now its same for both, i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
    at <anonymous>:5:68
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:875:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:808:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:664:21)

Comment: After the alert"GO" i get another one Alert which say "null"

Comment: I just now opened my fiddle and get 5 alerts whithout null anywhere. Check again.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_Ry7mNWKT4    check out this video i show you what is going on

Comment: but when i ran the javascript code from the previous answer is clicking the buttons as i wanted.

Comment: Did you have the time to see it?

Comment: Before pressing "Like" button, you have 6 elements, but after you have 16 elements. I dont really know what happened with markup after press Like button.

Comment: But even the first solution with the many lines is not working.... and when i delete the " && ele.getAttribute('title').indexOf('Like this comment') == -1 " part. is working fine. Maybe there is something wrong with this part of line? or no?

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('._4l5  .UFILikeLink')).forEach(btn => {
        btn.click();

});
```

This is the code that you are looking for. It hits the button with the class UFILikeLink which is INSIDE the div which has the class _4l5. And you dont have to worry for other buttons with the same class. Hope it helped.